# Given write mode, when we set 'readOnly' for string property, the behaviors is not correct

Tags: java, json, validation

I'm trying to use json-schema-validator lib from networknt to validate my JSON data based on the schema.

But it seems not the correct behaviour.

example schema for readOnly=false

```
{ "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema", "title": "Read Only Schema", "description": "Testing Read Only Schema Validation", "type": "object", "properties": { "firstName": { "type": "string", "readOnly": **false**  } } }
```

data need to be validated
`{ "firstName": "George" }`

test case

```
@Test void givenWriteModelWhenReadOnlyFalseThenNeedAllows() throws IOException { ObjectNode node = getJsonNode(); Set<ValidationMessage> errors = loadJsonSchema(false).validate(node); }
```

My case is, when sending an HTTP POST request to create an entity, then need to check related properties which are configured as 'readOnly=true or false'.

if configured as `readOnly=true`, when we set `readOnly` to `true` for string property then need to trigger validation and report an error about can't change it, but actually, no any errors are got.
if configured as `readOnly=false`, when we set `readOnly` to `false` for a string property, it means the string property can be created/edited, right? if so, it needs to be allowed, but actually, it still gets an error of `$.firstName: is a read-only field, it cannot be changed`
Anyone can help me here or is something wrong with my understanding of this readOnly keyword? thanks in advance!